# Add user in domain1 to domain2 group with powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am looking for some powershell code that can add a user from one domain to another domain group.  I can't seem to find the magic code that will work that uses System.DirectoryServices.

```
############### 
# Query user 
################ 
# Variables 
$path="GC://ldap-server.company.com" 
# To limit the information returned add properties. Use an empty string to 
pull everything 
$property="objectcategory,distinguishedname,cn,mailnickname,samaccountname" 
$searchFilter="(&(objectClass=User)(samaccountname=joker))" 

$rootEntry = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry $path 
$search= New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher $rootEntry; 
if ($properties) { 
    foreach ($property in [regex]::split($properties, ", ?")) { 
        [void]$search.PropertiesToLoad.Add($property); 
    } 
} 
$search.Filter = $searchFilter; 
$searchResults = $search.FindOne();
$user = $searchResults.GetDirectoryEntry() 
$user_dn = $searchResults.GetDirectoryEntry().distinguishedName; 
# to find the first or only result, use $searchResults = $search.FindOne(); 

################ 
#Query group 
################ 
# Same as Query user, just change 
$property=""; 
$searchFilter="(&(objectClass=Group)(samaccountname=mygroup))";
$search.Filter = $searchFilter; 
$searchResults = $search.FindOne();

################ 
#Add user to group 
################ 
# From your group query 
$group_dn = $searchResults.GetDirectoryEntry().distinguishedName
```

I tried this, but it did not seem to add the user and is ADSI:

```
$Group = [ADSI]"LDAP://"+$group_dn
$User = [ADSI]"LDAP://"+$user_dn

If ($Group.IsMember($User.ADsPath) -eq $False)
{
    $Group.Add($User.ADsPath)
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't using the Active Directory module to do this?

Comment: This link will help you manage group memberships between multiple domains in the same forest (although it is ostensibly for multiple forest environments) https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adpowershell/2010/01/20/addingremoving-members-from-another-forest-or-domain-to-groups-in-active-directory/

Answer (score 0):

I was unfortunate enough to have to [do this the hard way](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/foreign_groupmembers.shtml) once (a domain migration where the source domain was still on Windows Server 2008). What you need to do is add the user or group from the remote domain as a foreign security principal:

```
...
$group_dn = $searchResults.GetDirectoryEntry().distinguishedName

$fsp = New-Object Security.Principal.NTAccount('DOM1', 'username')
$sid = $fsp.Translate([Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value

$group = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://$group_dn")

[void]$group.Member.Add("<SID=$sid>")
$group.CommitChanges()
$group.Close()
```

If possible you should use the ActiveDirectory module (requires at least Windows Server 2008 R2 and access to the AD Web Services).

Comment: I did not have have luck with this.

Comment: It fails on this:
    $sid = $fsp.Translate([Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value

Comment: For username, are you using distinguishedname, mailnickname, cn?  Domain I grabbed via: $user_dn = $searchResults.GetDirectoryEntry().distinguishedName;
$split = $user_dn.Split(',')
$top = "$($split[-3]),$($split[-2]),$($split[-1])"

Comment: "username" is the sAMAccountName.

Comment: For the domain, you can do `$Domain = ($SearchResults.GetDirectoryEntry().DistinguishedName.split(',')|?{$_ -Match 'DC=(.*)'}|%{$Matches[1]}) -join '.'` to get a `child.domain.com` formatted domain name.